# Using a 48x48 favicon

Tags: favicon

I've generated a .ico file from a png, and the .ico file seems to contain three version of the icon, a 16x16, 32x32, and 48x48 image. When I reference the favicon.ico in a link tag, the image placed in the address bar  seems to be the 16x16 version.  How can I get the 48x48 version to show up there?

Thanks

Comment: The browser will automatically use the appropriate version of the icon. Are you sure that the real display size of the favicon on your PC is 48x48

Comment: No, I'm not sure.  How would I find that out?

Comment: If you're using a high dpi monitor then it probably uses the higher resolution version. But to make sure, use a ruler program. There are tons of that on google

Comment: try dragging the link to the desktop - you should see the higher resolution icon there.